# Hibernate - Ignore non annotated field without the need to add @Transient

Tags: hibernate

Is there a way (configuration parameter) to change Hibernate default behavior to consider non annotated field of domain class as to be persisted ?

I would like that Hibernate considers by default that non annotated fields are transient and must not be taken into account for persistence, instead of struggling to annotate all those fields with @Transient.

Comment: Seems to not be possible. Created a JIRA issue : https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8909. Hope it will be considered fair enough ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's possible with Hibernate annotations, according to the [Hibernate Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e2963):

> In the annotations world, every non static non transient property
>   (field or method depending on the access type) of an entity is
>   considered persistent, unless you annotate it as @Transient. Not
>   having an annotation for your property is equivalent to the
>   appropriate @Basic annotation.

Of course, with XML mappings you could just only add the properties that will be mapped.

Comment: It's a pity. I think it should not be very difficult in the Hibernate code loading the metadata during the loading to add an if/else to activate/unactivate this behavior. Thank you for your answer anyway. I  leave the ticket open in case someone find a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, it is really not good not to have a hibernate specific annotation to ignore fields which are parts of business logic but doesn't correspond to a column. I mustn't use `@Transient` as I, otherwise I have to separate DTOs from Entity classes which is so much work in my case.

However I found a workaround, I use `@Formula` annotation and give a default value in it. For instance;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {



    @Column(unique = true, insertable = true, updatable = false)
    @Id
    String userId;


    @Formula("0") // @Transient
    Integer nonDBInteger;

...
```

I know it doesn't seem to be the best but still it works for me.