# JPA @Transient doesn't allow serialization

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to not persist a field in my Hibernate entity class into the db table, but want to make it serializable. Googled around and noticed the JPA annotation @Transient can achieve this. However, after I put it on the field, it doesn't persist but failed for serialization. Any ideas?

```
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "MyObject")
public class MyObject implements Cloneable, Serializable {

    private ArrayList<Detail> details;

    @Transient
    public ArrayList<Detail> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(ArrayList<Detail> details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate - Ignore non annotated field without the need to add @Transient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431995/hibernate-ignore-non-annotated-field-without-the-need-to-add-transient)

Comment: Could you share some details? What exception do you get? What code are you executing?